# Pydantic does not validate the key/values of dict fields

Tags: python, dictionary, pydantic

I have the following simple data model:

```py
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TableModel(BaseModel):
     table: Dict[str, str]
```

I want to add multiple tables like this:

```py
tables = TableModel(table={'T1': 'Tea'})
print(tables)  # table={'T1': 'Tea'}

tables.table['T2'] = 'coffee'
tables.table.update({'T3': 'Milk'})
print(tables)  # table={'T1': 'Tea', 'T2': 'coffee', 'T3': 'Milk'}
```

So far everything is working as expected. However the next piece of code does not raise any error:

```py
tables.table[1] = 2
print(tables)  # table={'T1': 'Tea', 'T2': 'coffee', 'T3': 'Milk', 1: 2}
```

I changed tables field name to `__root__`. With this change as well I see the same behavior.

I also add the `validate_assignment = True` in the Model `Config` that also does not help.

How can I get the model to validate the `dict` fields? Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two distinct issues here that I'll address separately.

### Mutating a `dict` on a Pydantic model

#### Observed behavior

```py
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TableModel(BaseModel):
    table: Dict[str, str]

    class Config:
        validate_assignment = True


instance = TableModel(table={"a": "b"})
instance.table[1] = object()
print(instance)
```

Output: `table={'a': 'b', 1: <object object at 0x7f7c427d65a0>}`

Both key and value type clearly don't match our annotation of `table`. So, why does the assignment `instance.table[1] = object()` **not** cause a validation error?

#### Explanation

The reason is rather simple: There is no mechanism to enforce validation here. You need to understand what happens here from the point of view of the model.

A model *can* validate attribute assignment (if you configure `validate_assignment = True`). It does so by hooking into the [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method and running the value through the appropriate field validator(s).

But in that example above, we never called `BaseModel.__setattr__`. Instead, we called the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method that `BaseModel` inherits from `object` to **access** the value of `instance.table`. That returned the dictionary object (`{"a": "b"}`). And then we called the [`dict.__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) method **on that dictionary** and added a key-value-pair of `1: object()` to it.

The dictionary is just a regular old dictionary without any validation logic. And the mutation of that dictionary is completely obscure to the Pydantic model. It has no way of knowing that after accessing the object currently assigned to the `table` field, we changed something *inside* that object.

Validation would only be triggered, if we actually assigned a new object to the `table` field of the model. But that is not what happens here.

If we instead tried to do `instance.table = {1: object()}`, we *would* get a validation error because now we are actually setting the `table` attribute and trying to assign a value to it.

#### Possible workaround

Depending on how you intend to use the model, you could ensure that changes in the `table` dictionary will always happen "outside" of the model and are followed by a re-assignment in the form `instance.table = ...`. I would say that is probably the most practical option. In general, re-parsing (subsets of) data should ensure consistency, if you mutated values. Something like this should work (i.e. cause an error):

```py
tables.table[1] = 2
tables = TableModel.parse_obj(tables.dict())
```

Another option might be to play around and define [your own subtype](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#custom-data-types) of `Dict` and add validation logic there, but I am not sure how much "reinventing the wheel" that might entail.

The most sophisticated option could maybe be a descriptor-based approach, where instead of just calling `__getattribute__`, a custom descriptor intercepts the attribute access and triggers the assignment validation. But that is just an idea. I have not tried this and don't know if that might break other Pydantic magic.

### Implicit type coercion

#### Observed behavior

```py
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel


class TableModel(BaseModel):
    table: Dict[str, str]


instance = TableModel(table={1: 2})
print(instance)
```

Output: `table={'1': '2'}`

#### Explanation

This is very easily explained. This is expected behavior and was put in place by choice. The idea is that if we *can* "simply" coerce a value to the specified type, we want to do that. Although you defined both the key and value type as `str`, passing an `int` for each is no big deal because the default [string validator](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.4/pydantic/validators.py#L65) can just do `str(1)` and `str(2)` respectively.

Thus, instead of raising a validation error, the `tables` value ends up with `{"1": "2"}` instead.

#### Possible workaround

If you do not want this implicit coercion to happen, there are [strict types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#strict-types) that you can use to annotate with. In this case you could to `table: Dict[StrictStr, StrictStr]`. Then the previous example would indeed raise a validation error.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detail explanation. Unless I subtype like you mentioned above, I can't update the model instance with new data once the instance of the model is created, is my understanding correct?
My intent here is to create the instance once & update it multiple time. Is there a way that I can achieve this with the same data model?

Comment: @vsnag You can update it, just make sure you actually **assign** new values to the actual model. Just setting a dictionary item will not trigger validation. Only if you assign a new dictionary to the field. I also added an example of re-parsing after mutating the dictionary to the workaround section above.

Comment: nice, updated example above solves the problem. I am guessing  there may be some performance overhead with this approach but I am fine with that for now.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely not the most efficient thing to do. Glad I could help.